# How to create computed field in Odoo Studio using Python code?

Tags: python, odoo, field, odoo-10

I am using `Studio in Odoo version 10.0`. I successfully created the field with the name `x_studio_field_dZVpy` that appears in the `product.template` GUI.

When I try to edit the product name in the `product.template` GUI it gives me a `Value Error: forbidden opcode(s) in 'lambda'`.

I checked the "readonly" and "stored" check boxes. In the "dependencies" field I entered "name". I entered the following into the "compute" field in "Advanced Properties" section of the field.

I entered the following into the "compute" field in "Advanced Properties" section of the field.

```
def compute_product_dimension(self):
    for record in self:
        if product.name[:2] == 'LG':
            product_specs = product.name.split('-') 
            product_dimension = float(product_specs[6])
            x_studio_field_dZVpy = product_dimension / 2
        else:
            x_studio_field_dZVpy = ""
```

For example

```
product.name= LG-611-40M-3UM-95P-8.000
```

If the first 2 characters of the *product.name* is "LG" the code splits the string into an array and divides the 6th element in the array by 2. In this example this should divide 8.000 by 2. The "x_studio_field_dZVpy" field should then display 4.000.

[image: screenshot of Odoo Studio GUI with code]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
for record in self:
    if name[:2] == 'LG':
```

Try:

```
for product in self:
    if product.name[:2] == 'LG':
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still got the same error. So I deleted first two lines of code because I believe they are redundant in Odoo Studio GUI, changed "name[:2]" to "product.name[:2]", changed "product.x_studio_field_dZVpy" to "x_studio_field_dZVpy". Now I do not get an error, but the "product.x_studio_field_dZVpy" field value is displaying "0.00" and should be displaying "4.00"

Answer (score 0):

Computed fields in Odoo must have `stored = false` (unchecked). Dependent fields (`name` in this case) must have `stored = true` (checked).

Another error was Python arrays are zero based for example: `product_specs[1]` returns `611`. Revised `product_specs[6]` to `product_specs[5]`. I renamed the computed field `x_product_dimension`. This solved the problem.

**revised code**

```
for record in self:
    if product.name[:2] == 'LG':
        product_specs = product.name.split('-') 
        product_dimension = float(product_specs[5])
        record['x_product_dimension'] = product_dimension / 2
    else:
        record['x_product_dimension'] = ""
```